# Merge two queries to get the combined value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to merge the two SQL queries get the values in one place. I want to show year to date and week to date show amounts and units in one table with same cat

SQL query

```
select 
    `EmpsID`, `CAT`, `CHK_DATE`, 
    SUM(AMOUNT) as CurrentAmount,
    SUM(UNITS) as CurrentUnits 
from 
    `pays` 
where 
    `EmpsID` = 'SEMLAD01' and 
    `CAT` in ('Salary Pay', 'TRUCK ALLOWANCE', 'Expense Reimbursement', 'BONUS  (Accrued)', 'Phone Reimbursement') and 
    date(`CHK_DATE`) = '2016-11-12' 
group by 
    `CAT`
```

Second query:

```
select 
    `EmpsID`, `CAT`, `CHK_DATE`, 
    SUM(AMOUNT) as ytdAmount,
    SUM(UNITS) as ytdUnits 
from 
    `pays` 
where 
    `EmpsID` = 'SEMLAD01' and 
    `CAT` in ('Salary Pay', 'TRUCK ALLOWANCE', 'Expense Reimbursement', 'BONUS  (Accrued)', 'Phone Reimbursement') and 
    date(`CHK_DATE`) <= '2016-11-12' 
group by 
    `CAT`
```

Table structure

```
 EmpsID       CAT               YTDAmount   YTDUnits   currentAmount     currentunit
SEMLAD01   BONUS                 3000.00      0.00        0.00      0.00
SEMLAD01   Expense               1307.90      0.00       50.00     
SEMLAD01   Phone Reimbursement    272.00     50.00     1840.00      0.00
SEMLAD01   Salary Pay           60153.74   1840.00        0.00      0.00
SEMLAD01   TRUCK ALLOWANCE       4246.26      0.00
```

Comment: Use the UNION operator.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Among the others, which dbms? And what have you tried so far? And what do you need with MERGE? Do you want all the records from the first query UNION all the records of the second one?

Comment: I want separate values of first query and second query with units and amounts.

Comment: both query combined cat and show the values in  one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     select `EmpsID`, `CAT`, `CHK_DATE`, SUM(AMOUNT) as CurrentAmount,SUM(UNITS) as CurrentUnits 
     ,sum(case when date(`CHK_DATE`) = '2016-11-12'  then AMOUNT else 0 end) as '2016-11-12Amount' ,
      ,sum(case when date(`CHK_DATE`) = '2016-11-12'  then UNITS else 0 end) as '2016-11-12Units' ,
    from `pays` where `EmpsID` = 'SEMLAD01' and 
    `CAT` in ('Salary Pay', 'TRUCK ALLOWANCE', 'Expense Reimbursement', 
    'BONUS  (Accrued)', 'Phone Reimbursement')and date(`CHK_DATE`) <= '2016-11-12' 
     group by `CAT`
```